# Is it best practice to store data in HTML tags that don't have any content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it bad practice to do this in a template, or is there a better alternative? Is it okay to have an empty span like this in my code?

`<span class="stored-id-number" data-idnumber="1234"><!-- empty --></span>`

The reason I ask is because this currently seems to be the only way that I can store some data about multiple items that each live in a different template structure, and then reliably retrieve that data with JavaScript, like so:

```
// get all instances of this data item - where ever they may be
$('.stored-id-number').each(function (item) {
    var idNumber = $(this).data('idnumber');
    // do something with ID number in relation to this item
});
```

I seemed to me strange to add an empty `span` element just to store some data. But at the moment it seems like the only reliable way that I can do it.

Comment: You can store them with existing elements also, Why you need to create separate spans?

Comment: Can't you put it in any other element? <body> for general stuff... or in the parent <div> or something? Anyway, it doesn't really matter I suppose... no problem with having an empty <span> in your code.

Comment: This is one of what this attribute was made for. you won't add extra element to the DOM this way

Comment: @Satpal I need to do this as a global thing for several different layouts of current templates, therefore I thought that the best way to target all instances of this data would be to create a new element.

Comment: Yes. It's bad practice.

Comment: @Shaun can you please explain why it is bad practice?

Comment: Because most likely its bad design that has led you to the needing this in the first place. As others have said, if it is an identifier that is directly tied to the template, then IMO you would have that in the root node of the template (say a div) - that way it is clearly at the top (or on the element it relates to) - rather than just some random tag in the template.

Comment: i guess it would be better to have it on the root element of the template.

Comment: This is what localStorage is for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Rob making the jump that `localStorage` is the right answer is a bit of a leap. What in this question gave the impression that it should persist after a browser close, for example? Or that it should be visible across multiple pages within the same domain? I see nothing in the question that implies `localStorage` is the appropriate choice.

Comment: @dman2306 Well, his question says he wants to "store some data and then retrieve it" so my impression is that he is treating it in some way that is more appropriate in localStorage or something other than a data-attribute. data-attributes are attributes of the element and not for data "storage".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is designed for this in HTML5.
More about `data-*` here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Alternatively you could do:

```
<script>
     var store = {
          "myStoreId": 1234,
          "myOterStoreId": 9876,
     }
</script>
```

Access it by:

```
store["mystoreId"]
```

or

```
for (storeId in store) {
    var idNumber = store[storeId]
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Maybe you simple want an Array of "storeIds" ? Do it like that:

```
<script>
     var store = [
          1234,
          9876,
     ]
</script>
```

Access it by:

```
store[index]
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < store.length; ++i) {
    var idNumber = store[0]
}
```

Comment: Your current alternative won't work for me as there can be many of these elements on the page.

Comment: Or wait, maybe you only want an array of storeIds?

Comment: Forget the alternative. HTML is an excellent format to store data in. Think of XML documents.

Comment: there is no reason to bload it all into DOM, when its used by JavaScript anyway